# How to shuffle an arraylist once

Tags: java

So currently I am attempting to make a Deal or No Deal Type Program, and at the start I want the game to shuffle the values of the Arraylist so the player can't memorize the indexes of the arraylist. However, whenever I input the same number to choose a briefcase twice in a row, two different values come up. How do I make it so the arraylist will only be shuffled once, and not each time I input a number?

```
public static void main(String[]args) {


Collections.shuffle(array());
    for(int i = 27; i > 0; i-- ){
    System.out.println("Input the case number that you would like, the numbers are between 1 and 26");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int casenum = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(array().get(casenum));


    }

}


public static ArrayList array(){
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(001);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(5);
    list.add(10);
    list.add(25);
    list.add(50);
    list.add(75);
    list.add(100);
    list.add(200);
    list.add(300);
    list.add(400);
    list.add(500);
    list.add(750);
    list.add(1000);
    list.add(5000);
    list.add(10000);
    list.add(25000);
    list.add(50000);
    list.add(75000);
    list.add(100000);
    list.add(200000);
    list.add(300000);
    list.add(400000);
    list.add(500000);
    list.add(750000);
    list.add(1000000);




    return list;
```

Comment: `Collections.shuffle`?

Comment: How are the guessed briefcases being removed? If you are shrinking the list, the indexes are changing accordingly

Comment: I haven't coded that part in yet. However I will just be using list.remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[]args) {




  ArrayList myArray = array();
Collections.shuffle(myArray);
        for(int i = 27; i > 0; i-- ){
        System.out.println("Input the case number that you would like, the numbers are between 1 and 26");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int casenum = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(myArray.get(casenum));


    }

}


public static ArrayList array(){
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(001);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(5);
    list.add(10);
    list.add(25);
    list.add(50);
    list.add(75);
    list.add(100);
    list.add(200);
    list.add(300);
    list.add(400);
    list.add(500);
    list.add(750);
    list.add(1000);
    list.add(5000);
    list.add(10000);
    list.add(25000);
    list.add(50000);
    list.add(75000);
    list.add(100000);
    list.add(200000);
    list.add(300000);
    list.add(400000);
    list.add(500000);
    list.add(750000);
    list.add(1000000);




    return list;
```

you are creating new array each time you call array().get code
with this it should create it once, shuffle it on creation and then call that same array every time you input your number

Comment: Why use an `int` as a binary flag?

Comment: true, I'll edit

Comment: Whenever I do that it just results in the number chosen being  the number corresponding to the index.

Comment: can you explain your problem in a bit more details?

Comment: Basically I have an integer equal to the number that I input that I use to choose the index of a number in an array list. However, each time I input that number it results in the order of the array list being changed. IE(An index of 2 might equal 10 the first time, but for the second time 2 might equal 100)

Comment: can you add your code?

Comment: Yep, it is added now

Comment: I've edited my answer, please check it.

Comment: I appreciate all your help, however it is saying when I define myArray that it can't convert from void to arraylist. Any thoughts?

Comment: sorry. just write ArrayList myArray = array();
Collections.shuffle(myArray);
you can see edited code once again

Comment: please tick my answer as correct if it solved your problem. thank you

Comment: Thanks a million! I've been trying to solve this for several days